# How to add an invisible header to a text file?

Tags: c#, text, header, invisible

Good morning everbody,

I would like to know if there is a possibility to add an invisible text block to a text file. It could be a header or at the bottom of the file, it does not matter.

It should work like this, I open a text file I add my normal text, and before closing the file I add the secret text.
When I open it again I should be able to detect if there is any secret block that is written.

Is that doable? Is there any library that does this? I cannot find anything close to this (I work with C#)

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: No you cannot do this. If you can open a file and read it then you can see all the content. Perhaps you want to use this for secret information? If so look at encryption. Perhaps you want to store stuff you don't want users to mess with? If so put that in a separate file.

Comment: ok. so a separate file is a necessary solution... thanks

Comment: Only possible for a special reader you write yourself. Other than that: Text is text is text..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. If the data is saved in a file, it can be read. Hiding of data is impossible. It is either present (and thus readable), or not.

You only option would be to encrypt your data as mikelegg has commented above.